# Bypass capacitor placement

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I have the current schematic with a full line of capacitor which I suppose are by pass capacitor. As you can see the schematic show a unique point of connection on the 56 pin however I suppose that each capacitor is supposed to be close to a particular pin. How do I know which pin each capacitor should go with  ?

[image]

Comment: If the designer didnt' specify then they think it doesn't matter which capacitor goes near which pin. It is probably a good idea to put one capacitor near each pin (or group of nearby pins), to the extent possible.

Comment: The User Guide from TI at http://www.ti.com/tool/dk-tm4c123g includes a fairly high resolution picture of the top side of the board and renders of top/bottom side component placement on pages 4 and 20, respectively. That tells you where the layout engineer at TI decided that the capacitors should go.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I know which pin each capacitor should go with ?

You don't.

The designer of the circuit probably intended to do the layout himself, or have someone he knows and will communicate with closely do the layout.

In general, you want each power pin to have its own bypass capacitor.  In this case, there are fewer capacitors than power pins.  Unfortunately that means you simply don't know how the designer intended the capacitors to be placed.

This is obviously a large chip since it has at least 137 pins.  That may imply a grid layout of pins as apposed to pins along four edges.  In that case some of the pins that have rather different numbers may actually be near each other.  If there are such clumps, then probably there is one capacitor per clump and isolated power pin.

Note also the different values of capacitors, particularly on the Vdd pins.  The 10 nF were probably chosen for their impedance at such high frequencies that the 100 nF would actually have higher impedance.  That means the 10 nF are intended to by physically very close, probably immediately under the chip in case of BGA package.  The 100 nF a littler farther away, and the 1 µF back a few 10s of mm at the overall power and ground feeds.

Also, why do you assume this circuit was designed well?  There are a lot of crappy or badly documented designs out there, especially in those that got posted on the net.

Comment: the chip is TM4C123G from TI it comes from an eval board/dk, so I think it was design properly :)

Comment: @chris: This is something you should have mentioned up front.

Comment: sorry for this.

Answer (score 3):

If the designer didnt' specify then they think it doesn't matter which capacitor goes near which pin.

General rules you should follow as much as you can:

- Put one capacitor near each pin (or group of nearby pins)
- Prioritize putting lower values nearest to the pins. Place higher values after optimizing the placement of lower values.

Comment: We can see on the schematic there are 12 pins involved but only 8 capacitors. On the top part, there are 2 pins and 5 capacitors. How to deal with this case where capacitor number doesn't match pin number ?

Thank you for this : "Prioritize putting lower values nearest to the pins. Place higher values after optimizing the placement of lower values." this is what I was looking for partly

Comment: If the circuit designer didn't specify, then they are saying it doesn't matter which of the pins gets capacitors and which doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will find that there is a socking great copper pour for VDD, maybe even a complete plain, which pretty much makes the placement once you get past the 10n caps less critical.

It looks like you basically have three groups of power inputs one for a clock PLL or such, VDD for core logic and VDDA for some analogue stuff C206, 207 & 219 are priority parts and should be right next to (or under) the appropriate pins, then the 10nf parts on the VDD copper pour, then the 100nF stuff, then everything else.

C200 is probably another one that matters in its way.

Be a little suspicious of app notes (And even, annoyingly EVM designs), they are not always quite what you would like.

Regards, Dan.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I know which pin each capacitor should go with ?

A schematic does not specify placement at all. Note that this schematic also violates the "one 100nF cap for each VDD pin" rule that most MCU manufacurers write into their appnotes.

The manufacturer is supposed to provide at least some basic documents on how to layout a pcb for their chips. Look on their website for hardware design guides, application notes or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what micro-controller you are using, but TI has a System Design Guideline intended for the TM4C129's. It can be found [here.](http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/spma056) It goes into decoupling capacitor placement in section **3.4.3 Decoupling Capacitors**. Perhaps your vendor has a similar document or you can use this one as a reference.